# Django - How to filter a query, through an attribute of a foreignkey, which is also a foreignkey

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to filter a query using a foreignkey attribute, but this attribute is a foreignkey too.

I have to filter a list of OrderItems, filtering by the Supplier of the product in the order item.

OrderItem -> Product -> Supplier is the hierarchy

These are the models

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    # Relations
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order,
        related_name='items',
        verbose_name=_('order'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        related_name='order_items',
        verbose_name=_('product'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )

    # Attributes - Mandatory
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)


class Product(models.Model):
    # Relations
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(
        Supplier,
        verbose_name=_('supplier'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        Manufacturer,
        verbose_name=_('manufacturer'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )
    family = models.ForeignKey(
        Family,
        verbose_name=_('family'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )
...



class Supplier(models.Model):
    # Relations

    # Attributes - Mandatory
    name = models.CharField(
            max_length=50,
            verbose_name=_('name'),
        )
    corporate_name = models.CharField(
            max_length=50,
            verbose_name=_('corporate name'),
        )
    cuit = models.CharField(
            max_length=11,
            verbose_name=_('cuit'),
        )
...
```

Well, I can filter using the product name, etc, but I need to filter the OrderItems by the Supplier of the Product.

Thanks very much!

Comment: So you want all `OrderItem`s for a given supplier?

Comment: try `.filter(product__supplier__name= "somename")`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: @Chiefir i try that before ask the question and don't work

Comment: @marcosgue what was the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all `OrderItem`s for a given `Supplier` (well for `Product`s from a given `Supplier`), then we can use a filter where we use two consective underscores (`__`) to query through a foreign key.

So we can here use:

```
OrderItem.objects.filter(product__supplier=our_supplier)
```

Where `our_supplier` is of course the supplier we are interested in. Or if we for instance filter on the *name* of a supplier:

```
OrderItem.objects.filter(product__supplier__name=our_supplier_name)
```

Comment: arg, beat me to it.  The power of `__`!